# In python is it better to have a series of += or to append to a list and then sum?

Tags: python, list, sum

Both of these bits of code do the same thing:

```
g = 1
g += 2
g += 17
print g

g = []
g.append(1)
g.append(2)
g.append(17)
print sum(g)
```

I was just wondering if one of these ways is "better" or more Python than the other.
My own testing with the following bit of code:

```
import time

n = 1000000

A = time.clock()
w = 0
for i in range(n):
    w += i
print w, time.clock() - A

A = time.clock()
g = []
for i in range(n):
    g.append( i )
print sum(g), time.clock() - A
```

seems to indicate that the first method is slightly faster, but I may be missing something.
Or I may be missing an entirely better way to perform this type of operation. Any input would be welcome.

Comment: readability > performance.  also see timeit module for accurate timing.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? This seems like it would only be a question in a contrived use-case where something better would work anyway.

Comment: If you really care about performance, don't build a list, and don't loop in python; just sum an iterator (like islice(count))). Or, better, sum a range (xrange in 2.x). Or, better, there's a trivial constant-time algorithm for summing a range of numbers.

Comment: In other words: sum(range(n)) will be much faster than either, and n*(n-1)/2 will be much faster than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason to have the second method is if you plan to use the list `g` elsewhere in the code.  Otherwise, there isn't a reason to do it the second way.  Making a list and then summing its values is a lot more costly then just incrementing a variable.

Moreover, if incrementing `g` is your goal, then why not do that?  "Explicit is better than implicit" is a motto of Python.  The first method *explicitly* increments `g`.

Also, the list may confuse people.  When they see your code, they will think you *need* the list and plan to use it elsewhere.  Not to mention that `g` is now a list.  If `g` is supposed to be a number, having it be a list is not good and can lead to problems.

Finally, the first solution has less syntax (always a plus if it does the same job efficiently).

So, I'd go with method 1.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a matter of being Pythonic, it's a matter of what you want to achieve.

Do you want to save the values that constitute the sum so they can be referred to later? If so, use a list. If not, then why even bother with a list? It would just be a convoluted and less efficient way to do the same thing -- just add the values up. The direct addition method will obviously be faster because all you're doing is adding to a variable (very cheap), instead of mutating a list (which has a greater cost). Not to mention the evident memory advantage of using the direct addition approach, since you wouldn't be storing useless numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Method A is

1. Add the integers

Method B is

1. Create a list of integers
2. Add the integers

If all you want to do is

1. Add the integers

I'd go with method A.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely the first, for many reason, first of all memory allocation (N integer instead just one) and performance: in real world application the GC overhead would pop out.

Answer (score 0):

edit: disregard this, I can see now that it is not generally true, and is only true for specific values of x.

Ok, so I can see that making a list should be inefficient, but then why does fun2 run more quickly in this instance? Doesn't it essentially create a list and then sum over it?

```
import timeit

def fun1(x):
    w = 0
    for i in range(x):
        w += i
    return w 

def fun2(x):
    return sum([i for i in range(x)])

timer = timeit.Timer(stmt='fun1(10000)', setup='from __main__ import fun1')
print timer.timeit(number=10000)


timer = timeit.Timer(stmt='fun2(10000)', setup='from __main__ import fun2')
print timer.timeit(number=10000)
```